# How to record voice using ionic2 (media plugin)?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins

After installing the Media plugin, i followed the documentation steps to integrate the recording code.
this is my code:

```
`this.platform.ready()
 .then(() => {
const file: MediaObject = this.media.create('my_awesome_file.mp3');
file.startRecord();
window.setTimeout(() => file.stopRecord(), 10000);
});
```

and when i run it on real device i got this error message:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Comment: Where are you doing this? In the constructor? Are you receiving the corresponding arguments?

Comment: in custom function:
recordVoice(){}

Comment: It should be recordVoice(public media: Media).

Comment: This is cordova native plugin so it will be useful in actual device only, So make sure you are running the application in device.